# Xamarin iOS WKWebView DidFinishNavigation and DidStartProvisionalNavigation not getting called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I am implementing WKWebView in iOS Xamarin and i want to do something when load start and load finish. I have implemented IWKNavigationDelegate and added the following functions but non of them gets called. Am i missing something

Class definition

```
 public partial class MasterViewController : UIViewController,IScanSuccessCallback, IWKScriptMessageHandler, IWKNavigationDelegate
{ }
```

Navigation Delegate functions

```
    public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("DidFinishNavigation");
    }

    public void DidFailNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error )
    {
        // If navigation fails, this gets called
        Console.WriteLine("DidFailNavigation");
    }
    public void DidFailProvisionalNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error )
    {
        // If navigation fails, this gets called
        Console.WriteLine("DidFailProvisionalNavigation");
    }
    public void DidStartProvisionalNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation )
    {
        // When navigation starts, this gets called
        Console.WriteLine("DidStartProvisionalNavigation");
    }
```

Comment: did you assign the delegate class to your WKWebView instance?

Comment: I have - IWKNavigationDelegate as edited above. How do i assign a Delegate class to WKWebView

Answer (score 14, accepted):

complementing Jason's answer.

You are missing the required `ExportAttribute` for optional delegate methods, Xamarin Studio auto completion engine should generate this for you each time you implement any `IFooInterface` when `Foo` is an ObjC delegate and you type `override` (it should list optional and not optional members). `ExportAttribute` is only required for optional members (non abstract members in the c# interface).

[image]

In this particular case all members of `WKNavigationDelegate` ObjC protocol are optional so you need the `Export` attribute and the ObjC selector as its parameter.

You need to add `using Foundation` to your using statements, `ExportAttribute` is inside it.

```
[Export ("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("DidFinishNavigation");
}

[Export ("webView:didFailNavigation:withError:")
public void DidFailNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error )
{
    // If navigation fails, this gets called
    Console.WriteLine("DidFailNavigation");
}

[Export ("webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:")]
public void DidFailProvisionalNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error )
{
    // If navigation fails, this gets called
    Console.WriteLine("DidFailProvisionalNavigation");
}

[Export ("webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation:")]
public void DidStartProvisionalNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation )
{
    // When navigation starts, this gets called
    Console.WriteLine("DidStartProvisionalNavigation");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think one of the sources of confusion is that sometimes delegate are classes, sometimes (like here) are implemented as interfaces. Besides, the documentation says (regarding IWKNavigationDelegate): "If developers create classes that implement this interface, the implementation methods will automatically be exported to Objective-C with the matching signature from the method defined in the WKNavigationDelegate protocol". As a matter of fact, it's treated as a WeakDelegate

Comment: I've tried to add export the same way you did, but still `DidFinishNavigation` is not being hit. Please check my question if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63578856/9401556

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly assign the NavigationDelegate class to webview

```
WKWebView web = new WKWebView();

// if the current class implements IWKNavigationDelegate, you can do this
web.NavigationDelegate = this;

// or you can create a separate class that implements IWKNavigationDelegate
web.NavigationDelegate = new MyWebDelegate();
```

Comment: I have done // if the current class implements IWKNavigationDelegate, you can do this
web.NavigationDelegate = this; But still methods don't get called

Comment: Hello Jason, I've tried to your way, but still the `DidFinishNavigation` is not being hit. Can you please check the following answer on my question. I've tried it but now a white page is being displayed. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63579635/9401556