# Implementing Custom Webview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm new with `Xamarin.Forms` and I have implemented a custom web view renderer in `Droid` project.

The issue is when implementing the renderer in `iOS` project, it's like the `Webview` is initialized without loading the CSS and Javascript. Because it only display `HTML` page without any functionality.

After some research, I know we have to implement `WKWebviewRenderer` and we have to load the `LoadFileUrl` method in `iOS` but I still can't catch the url in the renderer.

Anyone have an idea please about how to implement the following `Android Renderer` code into `iOS Renderer`??

**Custom renderer in Droid project:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyProject.Droid.WebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
    {
        private bool isMyCustomWebview = false;
        public IWebViewController ElementController => Element;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomWebview))
            {
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new Callback(this));
                isMyCustomWebview = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new Callback(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity));
                isMyCustomWebview = false;
            }
        }


        public class Callback : WebViewClient
        {
            Activity _context;
            public Callback(Activity _context)
            {
                this._context = _context;
            }

            WebViewRenderer _renderer;

            public Callback(WebViewRenderer renderer)
            {
                _renderer = renderer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Renderer");
            }

            public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
            {
                base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (_renderer != null && _renderer.isMyCustomWebview)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Show();
                    var args = new WebNavigatingEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url }, url);
                    _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigating(args);
                }

            }
            public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                if (_renderer != null && _renderer.isMyCustomWebview)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Dismiss();
                    var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
                    var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, url, WebNavigationResult.Success);
                    _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: Custom renderer in iOS project:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyProject.iOS.WebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    // Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer
    public class WebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null) return;
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config) { NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate() };
            SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
        }
    }

    public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {

            //get url here
            var url = webView.Url;

            // webView.LoadFileUrl(url, url);

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's how I'm setting the source and base url for the webview in the portable project:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("/embedded/pay", content);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = resp,
        BaseUrl = paymentGatewayUrl
    };

    //Adding Cookie
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    var domain = new Uri(html.BaseUrl).Host;
    var cookie = new Cookie
    {
        Secure = true,
        Expired = false,
        HttpOnly = false,
        Name = "cookie",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
        Domain = domain,
        Path = "/"
    };
    cookies.Add(new Uri(html.BaseUrl), cookie);
    webView.Source = html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the code of **Custom Renderer** like following .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{

    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null) return;
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config) { NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate() };
            SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
        }
    }

    public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {

            //get url here
            var url = webView.Url;

            //webView.LoadFileUrl();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A white page is being displayed now. And I've added a breakpoint to the `DidFinishNavigation` it's never being hit. It's like it's never finishing navigation I think

Comment: I'll update the question just to show you how I'm setting the webview source, maybe something is wrong from the initialization. And just to give you all details

Comment: Webview Initialization Code is added

Comment: Could you share the whole sample so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work since everything is blocked from outside, so you won't be even able to login to the application from outside:/

Comment: And also I just noticed that `onElementChanged` is being called before the post request and setting the `html` variable to `webview`. So after setting the `webview.source` entity. `onElementChanged` is not being called.

Comment: You could create a sample which contains the issue .

Comment: don't forgot to turn off of private browsing in safari